# max size image facebook

Tags: facebook, image

I have created a facebook application with a photo gallery. I have set the fluid canvas.
When I click on a photo and enlarges what is the maximum size that can hire?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the entire user's screen with your photo. Think of the Facebook Canvas as an iFrame to your webpage. There are no bounds on fluid canvas except for the size of the user's browser window.

Here's a great article that describes how to use fluid canvas (along with some examples of games that use this setting): https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/ It will help you visualize how much screen space you will have for your app with this setting.